# Sort and slice multiple arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have multiple arrays of objects `T -> where T : IComparable<T>`.
Each array contains unique elements. An element could be present in multiple arrays but not multiple times in the same array. I need to move all elements that are contains in all arrays to the front of the arrays (in the same order) and get the count of the elements (that are moved so i can have a slice of each array). What would be the most optimal algorithm perf/memory wise?

```cs
var a = new[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var b = new[] {7, 4, 3, 1, 2};
... (up to 8 arrays)

int length = SortAsc(a, b, ...)

// a -> {4, 7, 5, 6, 8}
// b -> {4, 7, 3, 1, 2}
// length = 2
```

Comment: In addition to what @RufusL suggested please also clarify what part you *don't know* how to implement - there are for example a lot of questions showing how to find "elements that are present in all arrays" or "move element in an array"... Also "slice" generally assume large chunks - it sounds like {1, 2,3,5} + { 6, 2,4,5} should produce {2,5,1,3} + { 2,5, 6,4} which does not sound like "slice" but rather just move to me

Comment: @RufusL i hope this is clear.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i am looking for the best algorithm, not for implementation

Comment: @ptp absolutely not clear - how "4,7" is "in the same order" as `t[7, 4, 3, 1, 2]` ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov [4, 7] are present in both arrays so they are move to the front in the same order

Comment: You say *"the same order"*, but didn't define what that order is. Are your just ordering them by value ascending? or by the order in which they appear in one particular array?

Comment: @RufusL by value ascending

Comment: Also, are you saying that `4` and `7` are present in *all* 8 arrays?

Comment: @RufusL yes extactly

Comment: You may want to define what "the best" means to you. Shortest code? (intersect + filter out elements + concat would be relatively short)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the most optimal between perf and memory

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Intersect` method (in `System.Linq`) to get all the common items. Then you can use `Union` to join the intersection with the original array. Because we specify `intersection.Union(array)` instead of `array.Union(intersection)`, the `intersection` items will appear first in the result. Also, the set operation methods (`Union`, `Intersect`, `Except`) will automatically remove any duplicates:

```
var a = new[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var b = new[] {7, 4, 3, 1, 2};

// Common items, ordered by value ascending
var intersection = a.Intersect(b).OrderBy(i => i);

// Union the intersection to put the intersected items first 
// (the duplicates are removed automatcially by Union)
a = intersection.Union(a).ToArray();
b = intersection.Union(b).ToArray();
```

To get the intersection of multiple arrays, it would be handy to add them to a list and then we can use the `Aggregate` method:

```
var a = new[] {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var b = new[] {7, 4, 3, 1, 2};
var c = new[] {9, 1, 7, 4, 2};
var d = new[] {3, 1, 4, 2, 7};
var e = new[] {3, 7, 4, 1, 2};
var f = new[] {7, 4, 3, 1, 9};
var g = new[] {4, 1, 7, 9, 8};
var h = new[] {3, 2, 6, 7, 4};

var arrays = new List<int[]> {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h};

var intersection = arrays.Aggregate((accumulation, next) =>
    accumulation.Intersect(next).ToArray()).OrderBy(i => i);
```

Note that this is not the best performing solution, just a simple one to write. :)

Oh, and you can get the count of common items using `intersection.Count()`.

Comment: Nice. Totally fails on "optimal ... memory" request as it is O(total arrays size) vs. O(1) for memory-optimal solution... But I strongly suspect OP added memory optimization requirement just to ... confuse people trying to answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oh, crap. I really need to learn to read.

Comment: Just to clarify me comment - it is very rare when single algorithm can be both most time and memory optimal. In in this particular case there is obvious O(1) memory usage solution (check every item against all arrays one-by one) that does not sound practical due to O(total_number_items ^ 2) time complexity. It also may be possible to speed up some of the checks  still in-place but code will be far more involved (as there is no in-place / no memory usage LINQ helpers).

Answer (score 0):

As per I understood, I made an example in a console app:

This is the program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new int[5] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            var b = new int[5] { 7, 4, 3, 1, 2 };
            var c = new int[5] { 4, 2, 1, 7, 9 };
            var d = new int[5] { 1, 2, 6, 4, 5 };
            
            var leng = SortAsc(a, b, c, d);
            if (leng.Arrays.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Length: {leng.Arrays.Count}");
                foreach (var item in leng.Arrays)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write($"{item[i]}");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            }

        }
```

This is the method:

```
public static ArrayKeeper SortAsc(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c, int[] d)
        {
            //order arrays
            a = a.OrderBy(o => o).ToArray();
            b = b.OrderBy(o => o).ToArray();
            c = c.OrderBy(o => o).ToArray();
            d = d.OrderBy(o => o).ToArray();

            a = a.OrderByDescending(o => b.Contains(o)).ToArray();
            b = b.OrderByDescending(o => a.Contains(o)).ToArray();
            c = c.OrderByDescending(o => (a.Contains(o) && b.Contains(o))).ToArray();
            d = d.OrderByDescending(o => (a.Contains(o) && b.Contains(o)) && c.Contains(o)).ToArray();

            var resp = new ArrayKeeper();
            resp.Arrays.Add(b);
            resp.Arrays.Add(a);
            resp.Arrays.Add(c);
            resp.Arrays.Add(d);
            return resp;
        }
```

This is a DTO to help transport data;

```
public class ArrayKeeper {
        public ArrayKeeper()
        {
            Arrays = new List<int[]>();
        }
        public List<int[]> Arrays { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the result:

```
$ dotnet run
Length: 4
47123
47568
47129
41256
```

Of course it's a POC and is just one way to do something like you want using LINQ, Lists and arrays;

Also I think it will need some kind of validation to be more dynamic;

Comment: This appears to move items that are not common in all arrays, placing `7` to the second place if it's present and then sorting the remaining items.